# C# program is not displaying output properly

Tags: c#

My assignment is as follows.

A certain ITEC exam has 20 multiple choice questions. Here are the correct answers:

```
1. B 11. B
2. D 12. C
3. A 13. D
4. A 14. A
5. C 15. D
6. A 16. C
7. B 17. C
8. B 18. B
9. C 19. D
10. D 20. A
```

Create a program that:

1. Creates an array that stores the correct answers (5 points).
2. Create a text file called Response.txt that is a simulation of a student answering the questions
   Only write the letter answer and only one letter per line. Remember your file must
   have 20 lines of answers from A, B, C or D. See following example
   A
   C
   B
   D
   C
3. Your program should read the text file and store the answers in an array
4. After the student’s answers are read from the file and stored in the array, the program should
   compare the array with correct answers and the array with the student’s answer and
   determine how many answers are correct and how many are incorrect .
5. The program should display a message indicating whether the student passed or failed the
   exam . Passing grade is 14 correct answers.
6. The program should then display the total number of correct answers, the total number of incorrect answers, and a list showing the question numbers of the incorrectly answered questions.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace ITEC_exam
   {
       public partial class ITEC_exam : Form
       {
           public ITEC_exam()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

               string line;
               int cnt = 0;

               //List to hold question numbers of incorrect answers
               List<int> incorrect = new List<int>();

               //Array to store correct answers
               string[] correctAnswers = { };

               //Array to store answers
               string[] answers = { };

               //Read the files and store answers in arrays
               System.IO.StreamReader correctFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\a_day\\Desktop\\Baker_Austin_c#_final\\ITECexam\\ITEC exam\\correctAnswers.txt");
               System.IO.StreamReader answerFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\a_day\\Desktop\\Baker_Austin_c#_final\\ITECexam\\ITEC exam\\testResult.txt");

               if ((line = correctFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                   correctAnswers = line.Split(' ');

               if ((line = answerFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                   answers = line.Split(' ');

               //Compare answers and compute the score
               for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
               {
                   if (correctAnswers.Count() > i && answers.Count() > i)
                   {
                       if (String.Compare(correctAnswers[i], answers[i]) == 0)
                           cnt++;
                       else
                           incorrect.Add(i + 1);
                   }
               }

               //Print Result
               if (cnt >= 15)
                   MessageBox.Show("\n\n Result: PASS");
               else
                   MessageBox.Show("\n\n Result: FAIL");

               //Printing score
               MessageBox.Show("\n Total number of Correct Answers: " + cnt);
               MessageBox.Show("\n Total number of Incorrect Answers: " + (20 - cnt));

               MessageBox.Show("\n Question numbers of incorrect answers: ");
               //Printing incorrectly answered question numbers
               foreach (int qno in incorrect)
                   MessageBox.Show(" " + qno + " ");

               //Closing Files
               correctFile.Close();
               answerFile.Close();


           }
       }
   }
   ```

The issue I am running into is I can not seem to get it to output the  list showing the question numbers of the incorrectly answered questions .

EDIT: the issue I am encountering is that I have made sure both the answer key and response file have the same info so the program should result with a pass and that there were no incorrect answers.

What is happening is that the program says there was only 1 correct answer, then it also does not list the answers it sttd were incorrect as well.

Comment: You read only one line of the files. How do your files look like? Is all information written in one line? What is the reason behind this condition: `if (correctAnswers.Count() > i && answers.Count() > i)`. Have you tried to go step by step through with the debugger?

Comment: B
D
A
A
C
A
B
B
C
D
B
C
D
A
D
C
C
B
D
A

Comment: hmm  in the notepad it is vertical but when I copy and pasted it output like that

Comment: the file is 20 separate lines

Comment: if (correctAnswers.Count() > i && answers.Count() > i)   is there to check the file as a exception handle;

Comment: if it is vertical in the notepad then you will get only `B` if you use `ReadLine()`. Have a look with the debugger `correctAnswers.Count` should be 1 and your condition is only true once at the beginning when `i == 0`. This is why you get only 1 correct answer

Comment: in the notepad I should have it horizontal with spaces then?                                        I made them horizontal and it registers the correct answer properly this time (whooops)

Comment: I want to thank you very much that fixed it entirely , all I had to do was change the txt file to have them all be on one line horizontally , instead of one vertical line.

Comment: I wrote you a solution for a vertical alignment of data

Comment: welcome to StackOverFlow. Dont't forget to mark an answer that helped you. This way people with the same question can see in future that this is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StringBuilder` (or just concatenate strings) like this:

```
            //Printing score
            MessageBox.Show("\n Total number of Correct Answers: " + cnt);
            MessageBox.Show("\n Total number of Incorrect Answers: " + (20 - cnt));

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (int qno in incorrect)
                sb.Append(" " + qno + " ");

            MessageBox.Show("\n Question numbers of incorrect answers: " + sb.ToString());
            //Printing incorrectly answered question numbers
```

Comment: The main issue is for some reason it will say that only 1 was correct ( i have made sure both the answer file and response file match)  and it does not list any of the answers it sttd were incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You are reading unfortunately only one single line from your file.
You code will work only if you have 1 line in your file.

If you have a column/vertical alignment of data in your file, I would suggest to use the `File.ReadAllLines()`. It will return a `string[]` with all the lines.

```
string[] correctAnswers = File.ReadAllLines("filepath");
string[] answers = File.ReadAllLines("filepath");
```

The other thing is your condition `if (correctAnswers.Count() > i && answers.Count() > i)`

You don't need it if the order in both files is the same. You can just simply compare it.

The for-loop should run until the end of the array that you are trying to index. If on the next exam you will have 24 questions this loop will break out of bounds. So a safer alternative would be to use the `Length` property or the array:

```
//Compare answers and compute the score
for (int i = 0; i < answers .Lengt; i++)
{
```

**EDIT:**

if you have a mismatch between the files, then a comparison could be dangerous so you could check whether both arrays have the same length:

```
if(answers.Lenngth ==  correctAnswers.Length)
```

and only then perform the loop and the comparison

Comment: thanks! I took  if (correctAnswers.Count() > i && answers.Count() > i) out ,  the reason I added it appears to have been caused by the mismatch on my txt files

Comment: if you have a mismatch a comparison could be dangerous. Check my edit